# Reinstalling Debian: ext4 partition is not primary

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub, ext4, debian-installer

[image: partition screen]

I previously had a grub bootloader with crunchbang and win7. Since then I reinstalled win7 which now boots it automatically. I stuck in a Debian install CD that brings me to the stage in the above image. The highlighted logical ext4 partition is my existing Debian installation. If I change the settings to make it bootable it warns me that's generally only for primary partitions.

The existing ntfs primary partition is just a storage disk the bootable windows 7 partition is on the 64gb Kingston drive.

Am I safe to switch the ext4 to bootable? Do I need to make it primary too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't have to set the partition to bootable. I run only dual-boot machines, and have never done this. 
Do you have a particular reason for doing so?

Comment: I just want to be able to boot either the Debian on that partition once I've installed it or the win7 on the 64gb drive.

Comment: Yeah, GRUB will handle that for you. So don't mark the partition as "bootable"; just format it as ext4, choose the mount-point (I'm guessing you'll use /), and proceed with installation. When asked, install GRUB to sda.

Answer (score 2):

Linux itself and most Linux bootloaders don't care about the type of partition that Linux is installed it, and don't care whether the partition is marked active.

Marking a partition as active is mostly necessary for bootloaders that are installed in the MBR and chainload a bootloader from a partition. Windows's bootloader requires an active partition (or at least older versions did, I think UEFI has made this obsolete; I'm not sure about Windows 7 on MBR partitions).

Many OSes, including Windows, need a primary partition when installed on PC partitions. But Linux doesn't care, it doesn't differentiate between primary partitions and logical partitions.

Comment: There are some BIOSes that won't even attempt to boot a system if there isn't at least one partition marked as bootable.